# Bash : weird behavior with variable contain

Tags: linux, bash, variables, dbus

I am using a simple bash function which executes a dbus command and retrieve its result.

```
getValue()
{
 local -i val   
 declare -a array

 array=($(dbus-send --system --print-reply ...))
 val=${array[7]}
 echo $val
 unset array

 if [ ! -z ${val} ]
 then   
  ...
 fi
}
```

While the dbus command return an expected value the function works fine. However, when the dbus is in a bad state :

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: ...
```

the "echo $val" returns 0 and the condition if [ ! -z "$val" ] is satisfied. How to avoid this incorrect state ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that when the error is produced, the exit status of `dbus` is non-zero (failure), you can add another check:

```
array=($(dbus-send --system --print-reply ...))
val=${array[7]}
if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ -n "$val" ]
```

`$?` contains the return code of the last command to be executed (`dbus` in this case), which is usually `0` for success. I changed your condition to `-n` to check for non-empty and quoted `$val` as it is generally considered good practice. The curly braces you used don't offer any protection against glob expansion, e.g. if `$val` contained a `*`.

Comment: Are you sure that $? contains the return code of the dbus command ? Because the command executed just before is val=${array[7]}

Comment: That's an assignment, which doesn't have a return code.

Comment: That's probably what you want -- however I had in mind a scenario of checking for rpm packages, where the not-found messages are a nuisance in the output, but helpful in the script logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the standard error of your command to join up with the standard output, e.g.,

```
array=($(dbus-send --system --print-reply ... 2>&1 ))
```